# Statement that is a mix of sarcasm & to make someone happy

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for this word but I can't think of it. It describes when you say something you don't believe in but know it's what the other person wants to hear. Such as:

> "I wish you the best of luck in your future relationships."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may have a little harder edge than you are describing but [sardonic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sardonic) can fit.

> sardonic: [American use] *showing an amused attitude toward someone or something that suggests a criticism but does not express it*
>
> [British use]: *showing little respect in a humorous but unkind way, often because you think that you are too important to consider or discuss a matter*

Cambridge Dictionaries Online

Comment: ah that's it!!!! It's been killing me all day

Comment: If it's a quote from an external source, add a `>` symbol at the beginning of each line, please.

Comment: In *my* version of BrE, *I wish you the best of luck in your future relationships* actually means *Now f****k off and don't come back!*

Answer (score 3):

maybe the word you are looking for is one of these?

**[facetious](https://www.google.com/search?q=facetious&oq=facetious&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.3059j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**: 
"treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humor; flippant."

**[reassure](https://www.google.com/search?q=reassure&oq=reassure&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.643j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**: say or do something to remove the doubts and fears of someone.

Comment: facetious is really close but was thinking of sardonic. Thank you so much for the help though!

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please always try to link a dictionary definition that you quote in your answer and cite the source as the other answers do. You can create a hyperlink with [facetious](web address).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sparing my feelings, spare me your

> **white lie**
>
> noun
>
> a harmless or trivial lie, especially one told to avoid hurting someone's feelings.
>
> [google: white lie](https://www.google.com/search?q=white+lie&oq=white+lie&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)